# how can i process ndjson by rxjs(Angular)?

Tags: typescript, ndjson

For example, I can send request to openai-api by http-client

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

return this.http.post(open-ai-interface).subscribe(...);
```

But, this interface returns ndjson, not json,
so, how can I process this? I want a typewriter effect

I have tried ndjson, but I don't know how to use it, or there's having a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simple trick :

```
const json = "[" + ndjson.replace(/\r?\n/g, ",").replace(/,\s*$/, "") + "]";
const jsondata = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: thank you for resp, if the resp of the query cost long time, we have to wait till all data received, maybe this is not the best way.

Comment: @ygz could you please mark the question as resolved, to help others when they face the same problem as you?

Comment: But this is not resolve my question